# Segmentation fault (core dumped) - Know where it falls, can't understand why

Tags: python

I'm using Pythin 3.6, opencv and ffmpeg, and I got: "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error, while I'm trying to save an Image.

I know that this error happens when a process attempts to access memory in a way that the operating system and processor cannot or will not allow, still can't realize how to solve this problem.

***Short program description:***

I'm reading videos from multiple directories, reading each video separately making some manipulations using ffmpeg, and saving each frame of the video.

**Clues that might help to solve this problem:**

1. My program worked on my videos, I took the same videos, reencoded them, tried again and got this segmentation fault (can't understand why this reencode can make this problem).
2. I have C-extension of python, and I believe that the problem is inside.
   this is the file:https:
   [github.com/chaoyuaw/pytorchcoviar/blob/master/data_loader/coviar_data_loader.c](https://github.com/chaoyuaw/pytorch-coviar/blob/master/data_loader/coviar_data_loader.c)
3. It happens on different file, let's say I'm running the progamm on 1k videos, it falls on first few videos, mostly different but close to each other.

When I'm trying to "connect the dots" and the error I'm getting of touching memory I'm not allowed to I'm just clueless...
I've tried using "valgrind", and got this ouptputs(note allowed to attach images:

[Screen shot from running: valgrind --leak-check=yes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVD4N.png)

One more:

[Screen shot from running: valgrind -v](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ow4Ym.png)

I've read valgrind "quick start" and I'm still reading more materials, maybe you guys have any Idea?

I'll be happy for your help.
Thanks!

Edit: Update after a week of debugging (at least trying to debug..)
So this is where the "segmentation fault" happens, at this line:

```
npy_intp *dims_bgr = PyArray_SHAPE(bgr_arr);
```

The full function code is:

```
static PyObject *load(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
  PyObject *arg1 = NULL; // filename.
  int gop_target, pos_target, representation, accumulate;

  if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "siiii", &filename,
      &gop_target, &pos_target, &representation, &accumulate)) return NULL;

  PyArrayObject *bgr_arr = NULL;
  PyArrayObject *final_bgr_arr = NULL;
  PyArrayObject *mv_arr = NULL;
  PyArrayObject *res_arr = NULL;

  if(decode_video(gop_target, pos_target,
                &bgr_arr, &mv_arr, &res_arr, 
                representation,
                accumulate) < 0) {
    printf("Decoding video failed.\n");

    Py_XDECREF(bgr_arr);
    Py_XDECREF(mv_arr);
    Py_XDECREF(res_arr);
    return Py_None;
  }
  if(representation == MV) {
    Py_XDECREF(bgr_arr);
    Py_XDECREF(res_arr);
    return mv_arr;

  } else if(representation == RESIDUAL) {
    Py_XDECREF(bgr_arr);
    Py_XDECREF(mv_arr);
    return res_arr;

  } else {
    Py_XDECREF(mv_arr);
    Py_XDECREF(res_arr);

    npy_intp *dims_bgr = PyArray_SHAPE(bgr_arr);
    int h = dims_bgr[1];
    int w = dims_bgr[2];

    npy_intp dims[3];
    dims[0] = h;
    dims[1] = w;
    dims[2] = 3;
    PyArrayObject *final_bgr_arr = PyArray_ZEROS(3, dims, NPY_UINT8, 0);

    int size = h * w * 3 * sizeof(uint8_t);
    memcpy(final_bgr_arr->data, bgr_arr->data + size, size);

    Py_XDECREF(bgr_arr);
    return final_bgr_arr;
}
```

I thought that "bgr_arr" might be Null vector, any other Ideas?
I've tried using also gdb, but the most useful thing I got was this output :

> 0  load (self=, args=) at coviar_data_loader.c:559
>   1  0x0000000000502d6f in ?? ()
>   2  0x0000000000506859 in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault ()
>   3  0x0000000000504c28 in ?? ()
>   4  0x0000000000506393 in PyEval_EvalCode ()
>   5  0x0000000000634d52 in ?? ()
>   6  0x0000000000634e0a in PyRun_FileExFlags ()
>   7  0x00000000006385c8 in PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags ()
>   8  0x000000000063915a in Py_Main ()
>   9  0x00000000004a6f10 in main ()

I'll be more than Happy for your help.

Comment: This will be very hard to debug without source code. But do you know which line produces the segfault? Have you tried running this step-by-step through a debugger like pdb? Also, if you're having trouble with Valgrind, there are plenty of [tutorials](http://cs.ecs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/tools/valgrind/) that can help, and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20112989/7315159) discusses using Valgrind with Python.

Comment: I've updated the post.

Comment: You don't have a version of Python with debugging symbols, so your Valgrind output won't be very useful. Please follow [this guide](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb) to learn how to get a Python distribution with debugging symbols, and rerun Valgrind with that.

Comment: However, your second screenshot indicates that there is a problem at `coviar_data_loader.c:559`, which is something you should check out. Also, please don't post screenshots of errors - please copy-paste the error contents instead.

Comment: Hi  @NiayeshIsky , Thanks for your it really help me to move forward and see where is the problem, can you please help to take one step forward , I updated the post.